# Remove duplicate elements from a linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8, linked-list

I was trying to read a program of removing duplicate elements in a linked list. I am confused about the break conditions put in the while loop. Below is the code.

```
public static <T> void removeDuplicates(SinglyLinkedList<T> list) {
        SinglyLinkedList<T>.Node current = list.headNode; // will be used for outer loop
        SinglyLinkedList<T>.Node compare = null;     // will be used for inner loop

        while (  current != null && current.nextNode != null) {
            compare = current;
            while (compare.nextNode != null) {
                if (current.data.equals(compare.nextNode.data)) { //check if duplicate
                    compare.nextNode = compare.nextNode.nextNode;
                } else {
                    compare = compare.nextNode;
                }
            }
            current = current.nextNode;
        }
    }
```

The statement `while (  current != null && current.nextNode != null)`  is confusing to me. If I remove `current != null` from the statement the output is produced same. Suppose the list is 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null. Now initially current is at 1 , then if we traverse the list and when current points to 3 , at that moment (current.nextNode == null) and if I use only `while( current.nextNode != null` , that does the job for me. Then why the author has used `current != null`. Please help me clear  the confusion.

Comment: Try passing it a list with no elements and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A completely empty list would have `current` be `null`. The dot is the dereference operator - dereferencing `null` causes a NullPointerException. Hence, calling that method with an empty list would cause an NPE whereas the correct action is to do nothing ('remove all duplicates from this empty list' is a job that can be done, and it is done by doing nothing - there are no duplicates in an empty list, thus, nothing to remove).

For a non-empty list, indeed, that part of the `while` clause is never going to be relevant. Given that it would never get there (the last node in the list would already fail the while clause due to having a `current.nextNode` of `null`).